# Pop up Based Notification

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am implementing a pop up based notification system where logged in user will receive a pop up on the website. But the problem here is when user is not on the browser and working on some other tools like excel, in that case he/she will not able to take action based on that pop up. Is there any way to focus on that window which has received new pop up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add some more details...

Comment: Have you looked into using desktop notifications? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification

Comment: @BimalDas Simply I want focus on my website (whenever pop up comes )whether I am on the website or not(May be I am working on some other tool but I am logged in)

Comment: You can use HTML5 notifications.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I need to use my own pop up box instead of browser notification.

Comment: Don't think that will be possible. At least, I hope it's not. Imagine how annoying that would be, if any and all web sites could bring the browser to the front at any time they please.